# How to verify that something was invoked as the body of some executor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Given the following implementation of some class:

```
private Executor someSpecialExecutor;

private SomeService someService;

public void foo() {
    someSpecialExecutor.execute(() -> someService.bar());
}
```

Assuming that `someSpecialExecutor` is always running the passed runnable synchronously in the current thread, how do I verify that `someService.bar()` is called when currently running in `someSpecialExecutor` and not outside of it?

I know I could create a class that implements `Runnable` and check that the executor is passed an instance of this class and check for the invocation of `someService.bar()` in the tests for the `Runnable` implementation. But I would like to avoid creating an additional class for this single purpose.

Comment: "is called when currently running in someSpecialExecutor and not outside of it?" - You have no (explicit) invocation of `bar()` in your test. So *if* `bar()` is executed at all, it must be from `execute()`.

Comment: @JimmyB I want the test to fail if the implementation is ever changed to something like this: `someSpecialExecutor.execute(() -> {}); someService.bar();`

Comment: Does it matter to you whether `bar` is invoked from inside some *other* executor? In other words, does it have to be specifically `someSpecialExecutor`, or are you just interested in "invocation through service" vs. "direct method call"?

Comment: @Thomas not sure what you mean by "invocation through service", but it has to be specifically `someSpecialExecutor`, because this executor will in the running application set up some thread local session state and `bar` needs to be run in that session state.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, would it be okay if some other `Executor` would run `bar` but you just made it clear that you would want to detect that as well.

Comment: So you want the test to fail if someone changes the test code in a way you don't anticipate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could make sure that `someService.bar()` was just called once in your test, which is the default for `verify`:

```
Mockito.verify(someService).bar();
```

This will fail if it was called more than once. Another way to be even more sure would be to also mock the executoreService itself and then use an `ArgumentCaptor`.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
Mockito.verify(someSpecialExecutor).execute( captor.capture() );
Mockito.verify(someService, Mockito.never()).bar(); // nothing has been executed yet

Runnable runnable = captor.getValue(); // get the actual argument
runnable.run(); // execute the runnable 
Mockito.verify(someService).bar(); // now the lambda should have executed the method
```

This way, you mock the executor, then check that the execute method is called once (without actually executing something). At this point, the someService.bar() method should not have been called. No you get the argument that was passed to the executor and execute it - now someService.bar() should have been called once.

Comment: The first one won't fail for something like this: `someSpecialExecutor.execute(() -> {}); someService.bar();`. But your second option looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `someSpecialExecutor` will always run the passed `Runnable` synchronously in the current thread, you can inspect the current call stack inside `someService.bar()` to determine whether the method is running in an instance of `someSpecialExecutor`'s class.

```
class SomeService {
    public void bar() {
        // check whether we've been called by 'someSpecialExecutor'
        boolean inside = false;

        StackTraceElement[] callStack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement frame : callStack) {
             if (frame.getMethodName().equals("execute") &&
                 frame.getClassName().equals(someSpecialExecutor.getClass().getName())) {
                 inside = true;
                 break;
             } 
        }

        System.out.println("bar: " + inside);
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't necessarily guarantee that you're inside `someSpecialExecutor`, it could be that the code is executed by some different instance of the same class.

However, by extending the above method, you could additionally test the call stack and see if you're inside `foo()` which gives you a stronger guarantee.

Comment: Instead of playing around with the stack trace, you could simply use a fake executor that sets the inside variable and a mock for the service that checks it.

Comment: That's the beauty of coding: lots of ways you can do stuff.